# Printing a large table with headers

Tags: jquery, html, css, json, printing

I am looking for a cross-browser solution to print a table with 100+ rows, where the header repeats on every page.

I am working with ASP Classic, using VBScript, Javascript and jQuery 1.11.1 in Chrome, and the solution must work in Chrome, IE and Firefox.

This is what I have tried so far:

1. I have tried [variants of CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page):

   `page-break
   {
   page-break-before:always;
   }`

This only creates a header on the first page, and not on any other page in Chrome. ([why is it still an issue, Google?](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24826)) So I threw that one away.

2. I spent the other day working with HTML DOM. The idea is to create a series of tables (i.e.: `document.createElement("TABLE")`), then have each table fit on  8x11 paper (landscape orientation):

   `var valT = 0
   var elem = document.getElementById(title);
   if (elem.offsetHeight / 970) {
       r = x.insertRow(varR);
       r.style.height = "30px";
       valT++;
   } else { ....`

This almost worked, **if** the height of the rows remain constant. Therein lays the problem: the row height does not remain constant. There is a lot of wrangling with that which resulted in frustration.

3. Because I have the data in a JSON object, I am considering a **JSON-to-PDF** solution. Does one exist that will meet the requirements (100+ rows, header on every page)

Before I bang my head against the wall, can anyone offer any working solutions?

Comment: Okay...I may have to [start from zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646835/print-repeating-page-headers-in-chrome). To quote [Mssr. Clarkson](http://ih1.redbubble.net/image.15801541.9408/flat,800x800,075,f.u2.jpg) "How hard can it be?"

Comment: I will revisit HTML DOM. Why didn't I think to use [pageBreak](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_pagebreakafter.asp) ?

Comment: Another piece is coming together. Using jQuery, instead of DOM [to measure the table's actual height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height).