# How to print headers and footers with React

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a form created in React, and when the user is complete they can view a stylised version of the completed form. I want there to be headers and footers on each page (i.e. name as the header and page number as footer), but have discovered that the @media print does not work with basically any browser. Are there any sneaky css tricks or similar that could get this to work, or even a React module that does this?

I have tried the solution found on [Print repeating Page headers in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646835/print-repeating-page-headers-in-chrome/25880258#25880258), but the header printed everywhere it was called, not just at the top of every page.

Comment: Could you provide some Snippet, CodeSandbox or StackBlitz project to check out your code, normally what you're asking for is done by the `Router` of the application.